# python yaml output string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

i am trying to dump a disc to a yaml file, and I want an format in special but I can't find to right way to get it working.

for example my disct looks like this:

```
data = {'key_one': 'starts \n some other values\n\n', 'key_two': 'starts \n some other values\n\n'}
```

when getting the dump:

```py
file = 'output.yaml'
with open(file, 'w') as file:
    stream = yaml.dump(
        data,
        default_flow_style = False)
    file.write(stream.replace('\n\n', '\n'))
```

I get the follow result:

```
key_one: 'starts
 some other values
'
key_two: 'starts
 some other values
'
```

and this is correct, but I want this format instead:

```
key_one: |-
  some other values

key_two: |-
  some other values
```

Is this possible? I can't figure it out.

Comment: The expected and actual results you show contain **different data**: the quoted variant has newlines in the the value, and variant with ``|-`` doesn't have these newlines. You can easily find differences when convert from YAML to JSON (e.g. [here](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv)). With PyYAML it is possible to change **representation**, but not the data: for representation ``|-`` being possible you need to have values without newlines.